# Fix malformed ellipses in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to fix malformed ellipses (`...`) in a `String`.

```
"Hello.. World.."
"Hello... World..."     // this is correct
"Hello.... World...."
"Hello..... World....."
```

should all be corrected to:

```
"Hello... World..."
```

---

The following regex handles any instance of **3 or more** consecutive `.`'s:

```
line.replaceAll("\\.{3,}", "...");
```

However, I don't know how to handle the case when there are **exactly 2** consecutive `.`'s. We cannot do something like this:

```
line.replaceAll("\\.{2}", "...");
```

For example, for `"..."`, the code above will return `"......"`, as the regex will replace the first 2 `.`'s (index 0 and 1), then the next 2 `.`'s (index 1 and 2), resulting in `"..." + "..." = "......"`.

Something like this works:

```
line.replaceAll("\\.{2}", "...").replaceAll("\\.{3,}", "...");
```

...but there must be a better way!

Comment: Just two or more periods replaced with three?

Comment: How about `line.replaceAll("\\.+", "...");`? This will replace any dot sequence (e.g. `.`, `..`, `...`, `........`) sequence with your desired `...`.

Comment: This is a "gimme teh codez" question. It should be closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace any group of two or more of `.`:

```
[.]{2,}
```

with `...`

Answer (score 3):

Why not keep it simple?

```
\.\.+
```

If you really don't want it to mess with groups of 3 there's this:

```
\.{4,}|(?<!\.)\.{2}(?!\.)
```

What this does is this looks for groups larger than 3 first then it looks for groups of 2. The special thing about "..." is there are 2 groups of ".." in "...". So in  `(?!\.)` you look for the 3rd "." after the first 2. If that 3rd "." exists then discard that result. This is called negative lookahead. To discard the 2nd ".." you have to perform negative lookbehind. So `(?<!\.)` looks for that "." before the 2nd ".." and this result is discarded if found.

Negative lookbehind can't be perform by javascript so I used one that uses the Java compiler.

Link: https://www.myregextester.com/?r=d41b2f7e

Comment: This works great, but users will have to keep in mind that when creating a Java String, they'll need a double escape character, as in String pattern = "\\.\\.+";

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by negation, detecting everything that *is not* one or more words followed by a "correct" ellipse, and fix the ellipse by using a regular expression like:

```
line.replaceAll("[^\\w* ]+([.]{1,})", "...")
```

this has the advantage of not replacing other punctuation than the malformed ellipses.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like below (in unescaped form):

```
(?<!\.)\.{2}(?!\.)|\.{4,}
```

[Online examples](https://regex101.com/r/qC2hG2/1)

Basically, in the two-dot case, negative lookbehind and lookahead are used to prevent them from matching the three-dot sequence.